# No payment method found after disabling the guest checkout

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

Iam using Opencart 1.5.6.4  and i have setted up sagepay payment method. Every was working fine but i have disabled the guest checkout. Now the problem is that while check out it start giving me the error

> Warning: No Payment options are available

let me know how to fix that problem.
Here is the website http://www.mendipmeats.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

Go to System->Settings->Options tab and check whether Guest checkout is enabled. If yes, please paste settings of Sagepay module.